# selecting date in date ranges wrong result

Tags: python, django

Following if statement occasionally gives wrong result. any idea why?

```
    if self.start_date <= datetime.datetime.now().date() <= self.end_date:        
        self._is_current = True
    else:
        self._is_current = False            
    return self._is_current
```

Comment: Use try/except to catch exceptions, print the message out and see what happens.

Comment: are you using timezones?

Comment: no, but I am in same timezone

Comment: @Acepts. I am not getting error , why exceptions?